# Creating Plugins in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React. I have experience with Vue.js. Vue.js has the concept of [plugins](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html) which allow you to inject functionality *across* pieces of your app. The pieces may be components, state management, router, etc. A common need for plugins is translation or logging. My question is, does React have a concept like plugins or services? If so, what is it?

I do not see anything similar to plugins in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). Several blog posts I've reviewed, do not seem to use plugin in the same way. How can one provide programmatically accessible functionality that is available globally throughout a React app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern is to use a [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for this. A fairly similar example to the [Vue.js plugin documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html) you've linked, would be something like this:

```js
const I18n = React.createContext();

function useTranslate() {
  const i18n = React.useContext(I18n);
  
  return React.useCallback((key) => {
    return key.split('.').reduce((o, i) => {
      if (o) return o[i];
    }, i18n);
  }, [i18n]);
}

function App() {
  const translate = useTranslate();

  return (
    <h1>{translate("greetings.hello")}</h1>
  );
}

// app initialization
const FR = {
  greetings: {
    hello: 'Bonjour!'
  }
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"));
root.render(
  <I18n.Provider value={FR}>
    <App />
  </I18n.Provider>
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The above is fairly limiting since a user would not be able to select their own language. A more complex example example would be where a user can select their language. Here is some inspiration on how you could implement this:

```js
// Create a component that wraps it't children in a context.
function I18n({ initial, dicts, children }) {
  const [lang, setLang] = React.useState(initial);
  const dict = dicts[lang];
  
  const contextValue = React.useMemo(
    () => ({ lang, setLang, dict, dicts }),
    [lang, setLang, dict, dicts]
  );

  return (
    <I18n.Context.Provider
      value={contextValue}
      children={children}
    />
  );
}

// Create the actual React context.
I18n.Context = React.createContext();

// Provide custom hooks to simplify working with the data.
// You could for example use a simple templating engine.
I18n.useTranslate = function () {
  const { dict } = React.useContext(I18n.Context);
  
  return React.useCallback((key, view) => {
    const template = key.split(".").reduce((dict, key) => dict[key], dict);
    return Mustache.render(template, view);
  }, [dict]);
};

// Provide custom components to allow a user to interact with your context.
I18n.LangSelect = function (props) {
  const { lang, setLang, dicts } = React.useContext(I18n.Context);
  
  const changeLang = React.useCallback((event) => {
    setLang(event.target.value);
  }, [setLang]);

  return (
    <select {...props} value={lang} onChange={changeLang}>
      {Object.entries(dicts).map(([key, dict]) => (
        <option key={key} value={key}>
          {dict.langSelect.label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

// All the above could be located in a `plugin/i18n.jsx` file, or
// wherever you would like to store it. The code below would be
// the usage of this "plugin".

function App() {
  // Wrap the parts of the app you want to apply the context to.
  return (
    <div>
      <I18n.LangSelect />
      <Greet />
    </div>
  );
}

// Then in a child component use eiter `useContext` or the custom hook
// we created earlier.
function Greet() {
  const i18n = React.useContext(I18n.Context); // access the raw context data
  const translate = I18n.useTranslate(); // or use your custom hook(s)

  return (
    <h1>
      {i18n.dict.greetings.hello}{" "}
      {translate("greetings.introduce", { name: "John Doe" })}
    </h1>
  );
}

// app initialization

// The dictionaries could be imported from a separate file.
const DICTS = {
  EN: {
    langSelect: {
      label: "English",
    },
    greetings: {
      hello: "Hello!",
      introduce: "I'm {{name}}.",
    },
  },
  FR: {
    langSelect: {
      label: "Français",
    },
    greetings: {
      hello: 'Bonjour!',
      introduce: "Je m'appelle {{name}}.",
    },
  }
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"))
root.render(
  <I18n initial="EN" dicts={DICTS}>
    <App />
  </I18n>
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/mustache@4/mustache.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Note that you don't necessarily need a React context. If you have a library function or something similar, you can just import it into your file and use it.